# Mysql Shutdown Unexpectedly while upgrading mysql 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to upgrade my mysql in  XAMPP.
PHP Version => 5.6.3
old mysql version => 5.6.21 Need to upgrade =>5.7.22(Which was only available to download in 5.7 series)

I followed these steps to upgrade:

```
Download latest MySQL but download the zip file not the MSI
Unzip the zip file to a location.
Shutdown Mysql process (no need to remove service) from XAMPP control panel.
Go to XAMPP folder, rename mysql folder to mysql_old
Copy the new unzipped mysql folder to XAMPP folder, in it delete the data folder.
Copy over the data folder from the mysql_old to the new mysql folder.
Copy over the my.ini file under mysql_old/bin to mysql/bin.
Copy over other ini and executable files from mysql_old root folder to mysql (XAMPP ini files, my-huge.ini, my-small.ini, etc..). in my case i copied my-default.ini
Run mysql process from XAMPP control panel. Should work. (You may need
to kill XAMPP first).-->Here I struck out and facing mysql shutdown error.
(OPTIONAL) Run mysql/bin/mysql_upgrade.exe -u USERNAME -p to update tables in the local databases that may have problems due to the version change.
```

I tried 
1.change port as 3307,3306,8111 in my.ini file as others suggested.
2.Go to mysql/data/ directory
   delete the ibdata1 & ib_logfile*(ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile101) file
    restart xampp server

mysql_error.log shows Following :
*2018-05-04T06:31:04.062353Z 0 [Note] c:\mysql-upgradexampp\sm3\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 9428 ...*

I ran XAMPP Control Panel as Administrator,but still it shows

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 
[mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  
[mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
[mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
[mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
[mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this 
[mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

With Command Prompt ,I am getting following Error
\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Please Some one give advice to resolve .Thanks